# Animations in Geometry Nodes

Tags: animation, rigging, geometry-nodes

I'm trying to learn geo nodes, hope someone could help me here.

Is it possible to trigger an animation through nodes? Also if i have multiple instances of it, is there a way to start the animation of each instance in different times?

To be more clear, i want to animate the growth of a plant with blooming flowers(just one type, which I modeled and rigged without nodes since it is too complex). Then the tree trunk grows while instances of the flowers start to grow triggered at different period of times.
Thanks for your time

Comment: "Is it possible to trigger an animation through nodes?" No, this is not possible and not the purpose of *Geometry Nodes*.

Comment: i think you can via some "workarounds". e.g. you could move empties via GN which are the IK targets. But of course quellenform is right - this is not the purpose of it, but you can do it. And sometimes it makes sense ;) e.g. i made some automated walking of robots over a landscape via GN

Comment: It seems a good idea,Thank you @Chris!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic node setup from which you maybe can learn how you can start animations offseted by index:

[image]

result:

[image]